# How to check if a trigger is running at the same time?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a project that uses the Google Forms installable trigger. When it runs, it does a series of processes with the data and then feeds it into a spreadsheet.

The problem is that sometimes some people fill out the form within the same minute, and the variable that stores the position of the next line contains the same number in both runs. I figured that if I could get information about the current execution and check if there were any others in parallel, I would be able to solve this problem.

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Comment: `Lock Service`.

Comment: If your getting your data from that last line of the spreadsheet then don't.  Use values or namedValues from the event object instead.  And Lock Service maybe too.  Sheets that are heavily edited by multiple users are not good candidates for onEdit functions.  OnEdit functions are a bit slow.

Comment: Would this snippet do the trick? And thanks for the answers!

`var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
lock.waitLock(30000);

var nextLine = sheet.getLastRow()+1;
sheet.setValues(row);

lock.releaseLock();`